# a macro to count bits that are on (set)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

My task is to write a macro that checks how many elements in an array of INTs has excatly 5 bits that are on.

I know a macro is a very risky way of doing it, but that is the question that appears in some exams.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define RESULT 5
#define SIZE 8
#define BITW(arr, length, counter)\
    int mask=0b00000001, bits=0, i=0, j=0;\
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){\
        for (j=0; j<sizeof(arr[i])*SIZE; j++){\
            if(mask&arr[i]>>j)\
                bits++;\
        }\
        if (bits==RESULT)\
            counter++;\
    }
int main(void){
    int arr[4]={0b11111000,0b11100011,0b11001100,0b11000000};
    int res=0; int counter=0;
    BITW(arr, 4, counter);
    printf("%d",counter);


}
```

The problem with macros is that I can't debug my code. I went over it a few times with no success but I realized I got the result 1 instead of 2.

The counter variable is the one that counts how many elements has 5 bits on. The bit variable counts in a certain element how many bits are on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the assignment **require** you to use a macro to count the bits and/or to test the elements in the array? (That is a very bad idea.)

Comment: If you are on a POSIX platform, you could try to use clang as a compiler. It is capable of tracing origin of statements into macro definitions quite efficiently.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, that task requires both. I agree with you.

Comment: To debug a macro of that sort, replace it with a subroutine and debug the subroutine.

Comment: And make sure you don't infringe patent 6,516,330 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro fails to set `bits` to zero before counting the bits in each array element. It sets `bits` to zero only before the loop over the entire array.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I would probably do something like this, if you really want a macro:

```
static const int bits_per_nibble[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4 };
#define BITS_PER_U8(x) (bits_per_nibble[(x) & 0xf] + bits_per_nibble[((x) >> 4) & 0xf])
#define BITS_PER_U16(x) (BITS_PER_U8((x) & 0xff) + BITS_PER_U8(((x) >> 8) & 0xff))
#define BITS_PER_U32(x) (BITS_PER_U16((x) & 0xffff) + BITS_PER_U16(((x) >> 16) & 0xffff))
```

Defining `BITS_PER_U64` should be an obvious extension, if it's needed.

However, doing this as a small inline function would be a lot safer and a better solution...

There's also [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel), which has a whole section on ways to get the "population count" in various ways...

Answer (score 1):

I said

> ```
> if(mask&arr[i]>>j)\
>     bits++;\
> ```
>
> is wrong, because it tests if ANY bit in the result is set, not if all
>   of them are set. I'd rewrite the code to count the number of bits in 1
>   byte to
>
> ```
> bits=0;
> for (mask=0b10000000; mask!=0; mask=mask>>1)
>     if (arr[i]&mask)
>         bits++;
> if (bits==5)
>     ...
> ```
>
> Note this works only if mask is either unsigned or has more than 8 bits, so a char won't > do (your int is ok though).

but that was wrong.

However,

```
#define BITW(arr, length, counter)\
int mask=0b00000001, bits=0, i=0, j=0;\
for (i=0; i<length; i++){\
    bits=0;                         //<---- This line is missing from your code
    for (j=0; j<sizeof(arr[i])*SIZE; j++){\
        if(mask&arr[i]>>j)\
            bits++;\
    }\
    if (bits==RESULT)\
        counter++;\
}
```

doesn't reset the bits counter for each byte.

To debug the macro, first, write a function you can debug; then, when you're sure it works, convert the function to a macro.

Comment: The same what I wanted to say. Write function which you can debug and then, after fixing all errors, substitute to the macro definition.

Comment: In `mask&arr[i]>>j`, `>>` binds before `&`, so this shifts `arr[i]` and then performs the `&`. The `mask` has one bit set, so the result is a test for a single bit, not any of the bits.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm What I though is to test every time the RIGHTEST bit. If I have the number 00001100 then if j is 2 I move the bits 2 times that I test the mask versus 00000011 and the last bit (1) is set, so I add 1 the bits variable. Thank you for your answer but I still don't understand why my way is wrong, except for the fact that a macro is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your code. This part actually is correct. The problem is, however, that you don't reset bits=0 at the start of the outer loop.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Oh dear god. Thank you. This indeed was the problem. I appriciate your answer and help, and your code is a good example for another solution for that problem!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem has been answered by Eric.

> The problem with macros is that I can't debug my code.

You could make use of printf's in macro, or you could substitute the macro call with the code segment in the macro.