# Check the number of set bits is 2 or more in bit negation number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to check the number of set bits is 2 or more in negation of number. I'm trying to do that with checking if number is power of 2. But it's not working with negation of number. This is my code:

```
unsigned long int x = ~x; //x is given number
if(!(x & (x - 1))) printf("it have only one set bit);
```

Do you have any sugestion?

Comment: Didn't really get what you need. If it is to count bits, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21863332/2002198

Comment: I only want to check binary negation of given number has got 1 or (2 and more) set bits. I not need to know exact number of set bits.

Comment: You know how to test if a number has 1 bit set. Any non-zero number that doesn't have 1 bit set has at least 2 bits set.

Comment: What does "not working" mean and do you have a specific failing test case?

Comment: I loop through positive (from 1 to 75kk) int and check it and my program return all of it have 2 or more set bits.

Comment: I am not sure but i think problem is that bit negation of int give negative int

Comment: The smallest 32bit number whose complement does *not* have at least 2 bits set is 0x7fffffff, so checking up to 75M is not enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query about working out whether number is a power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666647/query-about-working-out-whether-number-is-a-power-of-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best solutions for finding the number of set bits (the population) in an unsigned integer representation of a number is with the [**Stanford Bit Twiddling Hack**](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel):

```
/* get number of 1's in binary number (population - pop) */
int getn1s (unsigned v) {
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
    return (((v + (v >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

It has been published in a number of variations, and there is a general form available for up to 128-bit numbers as well.

Comment: If I understood correctly, OP does not want population count.  See the comment "_I only want to check binary negation of given number has got 1 or (2 and more) set bits. I not need to know exact number of set bits._"